# Angular2 - Sharing a singleton service between components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an angular2 app with the following component structure:

**app**

**-- mapView**

while both components should have reference to the same service `SimpleMapService`, containing a third party control (esri map)

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
import { SimpleMapService } from './services/map.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [SimpleMapService]);
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleMapService } from '../services/map.service';
import { MapViewComponent } from '../esri/map-view.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'myApp',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/app.component.html',
    directives: [MapViewComponent]

})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {            

    constructor(
        private _mapService: SimpleMapService
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this._mapService.doSomethingWithTheService();
    }

}
```

map-view.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleMapService } from '../services/map.service';
import { Map, MapView } from 'esri-mods';

@Component({
    selector: 'map-view',
    template: '<div id="mapView"></div>'
})
export class MapViewComponent {
    @Output() viewCreated = new EventEmitter();

    view: any = null;

    public zoom = 10;

    constructor(
        private _mapService: SimpleMapService,
        private elRef: ElementRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.view = new MapView({
            container: this.elRef.nativeElement.firstChild,
            map: this._mapService.map,
            zoom: 10,
            center: [19.937, 50.061],
            rotation: 0
        })

        this.view.then(function(view) {
            this.viewCreated.next(view);
        }.bind(this));

        this.view.watch('zoom', function(newVal, oldVal, propertyName) {
            this.zoom = newVal;
        }.bind(this));

    }

}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, FeatureLayer, GraphicsLayer } from 'esri-mods';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleMapService {
    map: any = null;

    public doSomethingWithTheService() : void {
        this.map.doSomething(); 

    }

    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map({
            basemap: 'streets'
        });

    }
}
```

My problem:
- The `MapViewComponent` can successfully access the service while the `AppComponent` cannot:

> platform-browser.umd.js:962 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'doSomethingWithTheService' of undefined

I suppose I'm not sharing/handling the service correctly?!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. You could try to provide `SimpleMapService` in `@Component({ providers: [SimpleMapService], ...)` in `AppComponent` (and only in `AppComponent` - remove it from bootstrap and don't add it anywhere else).

Comment: Hint. Instead of `this.view.then(function(view) {
            this.viewCreated.next(view);
        }.bind(this));
` you can also use `this.view.then((view) => {
            this.viewCreated.next(view);
        });
`

Comment: Hi and thank you. This is exactly how I've done it initially, but it also doesn't work. It gives me the exact same error message.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps something with your configuration.